# Problems returning const char* from function

Tags: c++, arduino

First, thanks for taking some time helping me.

I am working on Arduino, and the thing is that I need to return a const char* on a function.

What I need to do is to create a String and send the response back. **Things like this are not working:**

```
...
String myVar= "Return Message";
return RPC_Response(myVar);
}
```

This didn't work, the String seems to be erased. Since I just get a blank response:

```
...
    const char* ch = new char;
    String myVar= "Return Message";
    ch = myVar.c_str();
    
    return RPC_Response(ch); 
}
```

But it only works If I do something like this: (But I need to create a String dynamically...)

```
. .

char *msg1 = "Return Message";
return RPC_Response(chmsg1); 
}
```

Or something like this:

```
. .

return RPC_Response("Return Message"); 
}
```

I have tried almost everything but nothing works...

Please...! Any idea of what Can I do???

Comment: The local variable `myVar` gets destroyed after the function returns and `myVar.c_str()` becomes a pointer to nowhere. String literals are special: they have a lifetime of the whole program. What you can do depends on what `RPC_Response` is and, in particular, what its constructor does.

Comment: Why can't you return a `std::string` and adjust the code at the function call site?

Comment: Here we go again (and again and again and again). `int foo = 0; foo = 42;` Do you expect `0` to leave any trace inside `foo` after another value was assigned to it? Pointers are not magical. You assign a value to them, the previous value is gone. Forgotten. Lost in space. It could have never existed. That `char` you allocated is now a memory leak. I'm not even talking about `new char`. How many characters did you expect to fit in there?

Comment: What is `RPC_Response`? Please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you could simplify your code to the following:

```cpp
    std::string myVar= "Return Message";
    return RPC_Response(myVar.c_str());
```

This will not work though, because the result of [`c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) gets invalidated when a string gets modified, including the string being destroyed.

The reason using a string literal works is because string literals are stored globally. (It's actually implementation defined, but typically it is done so)

```cpp
// storing it in a char* variable first is equivalent
return RPC_Response("Return Message");
```

Assuming `RPC_Response` only accepts C-strings, you would have do to this:

```cpp
#include <string.h>
...

std::string myVar = "Return Message";
char* str = strdup(myVar.c_str());
return RPC_Response(str);
```

Comment: Thanks so much.... It worked! BUT only having a String generated like "Return Message". What if the String is generated dynamically withing a "For" loop? There, every round I need to update the value of std::string myVar for a new one adding chars... Could you please help me with this? @J-Schultke

Comment: @user3578894 in the example I provided, you can just generate `myVar` any way you like, it doesn't need to be a constant. Just put `std::string myVar` outside the loop and update it inside of the loop before calling `strdrup`.